# Soap Web services monitoring, telemetry and metrics with node.js

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

For rest apis, there are libraries like swagger-stats and prometheus-api-metrics to support api metrics / telemetry. I am using node-soap, is there a library that supports web services metrics / telemetry?

I've tried searching npmjs.com but couldn't find much.